# Styling is different when included via <link> tag

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I'm having a very strange problem. Here's the HTML that I'm using:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type='text/css'>
        <title>Site name</title>
            *{
                padding: 0px;
                margin: 0px;
                
                font-family: sans-serif;
            }
            
            html{
                background: #BED4EB;
            }
            
            body{
                background: #FFFFFF;
                width: 1000px;
                margin: 0px auto;
                padding-bottom: 25px;
            }
            
            header{
                background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #004F9E 0%, #00284F 100%);
                
                padding: 10px 0px;
            }
                header h1{
                    color: #FFFFFF;
                    display: inline;
                    font-size: 2.5em;
                }
                header nav{
                    display: inline-block;
                    float: right;
                }
                    header nav ul li{
                        margin: 0px 20px;
                        
                        display: inline-block;
                    }
                        header nav ul li a{
                            color: #FFFFFF;
                            
                            text-decoration: none;
                            
                            font-size: 1.4em;
                        }
                        header nav ul li a:hover{
                            color: #FFA54D;
                        }
            
            section#quick_login{
                width: 20%;
                float: right;
                background: #91A9FA;
                border: 1px solid #5D82FC;
                margin: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
                padding: 5px;
                text-align: center;
            }
                section#quick_login input{
                    padding: 3px;
                    border-radius: 3px;
                    border: 1px solid #BDBDBD;
                }
            
            section#notices{
                display: inline-block;
                width: 75%;
            }
                section#notices .alert, section#notices .notice{
                    padding: 5px;
                    display: inline-block;
                }
                section#notices .alert{
                    background: #FA9191;
                    border: 1px solid #FC5D5D;
                }
                section#notices .notice{
                    background: #91A9FA;
                    border: 1px solid #5D82FC;
                }
                    
            section#main h2{
                margin-top: 25px;
            }
            section#main p{
                margin-top: 5px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <h1>Site name</h1>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href='#'>Link 1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href='#'>Link 2</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href='#'>Link 3</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href='#'>Link 4</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href='#'>Link 5</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
        
        <section id='quick_login'>
            <h2>Quick login</h2>
            <form action='login.php'>
                Username: <input type='text' placeholder='Your username' name='username' />
                <br />Password: <input type='password' placeholder='Your password' name='password' />
                <br /><input type='submit' value='Go' />
            </form>
        </section>
        
        <section id='notices'>
            <p class='alert'>
                Your email address hasn't been verified; check your email for a link to verify it.
            </p>
            <p class='notice'>
                We received a record 553 visitors yesterday!
            </p>
        </section>
        
        <section id='main'>
            <h2>Subtitle 1</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nisl risus, viverra eu sollicitudin volutpat, ultricies vel sapien. Cras in felis eu justo mattis convallis vel et orci. Maecenas consequat fermentum magna, sit amet dapibus nulla pulvinar venenatis. Nullam nulla mi, consectetur id diam at, pulvinar tempus diam. Morbi suscipit odio nec arcu ultricies dignissim. Curabitur consectetur libero lectus, ornare sodales tellus congue nec. Nam id tellus id nulla eleifend condimentum.</p>
            
            <h2>Subtitle 2</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris lacus nisi, mattis vitae volutpat tempus, suscipit nec lorem. Quisque posuere lectus odio, porttitor sagittis ligula ullamcorper quis. Vivamus ornare ut sapien in rutrum. Nullam et porttitor metus. Curabitur ornare orci sit amet aliquam rutrum. Phasellus scelerisque dignissim tellus in dictum. Pellentesque eu nibh purus. Nulla scelerisque sodales urna in feugiat. Maecenas et eleifend neque. Sed dolor turpis, congue et nisl quis, euismod bibendum magna. Sed eget laoreet urna.</p>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

and it displays perfectly (apart from the not vertically aligned menu which I'm working on):

[image: correct]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/67f6acd6397fb4551e1852ba91836a24.png))</sub>

but then when I replace the `<style>` tag with `<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='style.css' />` and copy/paste everything within the `<style>` tags into style.css it displays like this:

[image: why?]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/5cf93936ef4afa0031a5f64bbc3e8ce2.png))</sub>

What's causing this? How do I fix it? It appears to be browser-specific, since Firefox is displaying it perfectly. Only in Chrome does it appear incorrectly.

Comment: What directory is your css file in? Is it in the same folder as your html page?

Comment: Try using double quotes

Comment: @brouxhaha Double quotes and single quotes work exactly the same in HTML. Although, I tried it anyway, and it's still displaying incorrectly.

Comment: Perhaps it's a caching issue? Try doing a hard refresh (shift+refresh) or manually clear the browser's cache. I assume you don't have the `<style>` tags in the css file (not sure that would actually cause an issue)?

Comment: @brouxhaha Hard refreshing didn't work. I don't have the `<style>` tags in the .css file either.

Comment: Not reproduceable with the code posted.

Comment: Just noticed this guy: `<h1>Site name</h2>`. See if fixing this fixes your issue.

Comment: @brouxhaha Thanks for pointing that out! It didn't seem to fix it though.

Comment: Why is the page title inside a style tag?

Comment: I am nearly 100% sure that there is another rule overriding the one you are trying to use.. Can you try (just to make sure) with the !important on the style you want and then work it out from there?

Comment: Is this still an issue? As others have said I'm fairly certain this will be a style overriding issue as local styles take precedence over external stylesheets. Do you have any other stylesheets, or include an external components? Does this happen on multiple browsers, could it be a browser plugin? A link or JS Fiddle would help.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is caused by the `header h1 { display: inline; }` rule not being properly followed.

If you disable this rule when the css included within the page, then this causes the broken rendering you are experiencing with the stylesheet included via a link tag.

Additionally, the title tag should be directly under the head and not in the style section.

Answer (score 1):

The title tag is in the style section and is causing the header to display improperly http://jsfiddle.net/Paul_Geronca/2ZCVw/4/

Fix it to this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type='text/css'>
        <title>Site name</title>
            *{
                padding: 0px;
                margin: 0px;

                font-family: sans-serif;
            }

            html{
                background: #BED4EB;
            }

            body{
                background: #FFFFFF;
                width: 1000px;
                margin: 0px auto;
                padding-bottom: 25px;
            }

            header{
                background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #004F9E 0%, #00284F 100%);

                padding: 10px 0px;
            }
                header h1{
                    color: #FFFFFF;
                    display: inline;
                    font-size: 2.5em;
                }
                header nav{
                    display: inline-block;
                    float: right;
                }
                    header nav ul li{
                        margin: 0px 20px;

                        display: inline-block;
                    }
                        header nav ul li a{
                            color: #FFFFFF;

                            text-decoration: none;

                            font-size: 1.4em;
                        }
                        header nav ul li a:hover{
                            color: #FFA54D;
                        }

            section#quick_login{
                width: 20%;
                float: right;
                background: #91A9FA;
                border: 1px solid #5D82FC;
                margin: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
                padding: 5px;
                text-align: center;
            }
                section#quick_login input{
                    padding: 3px;
                    border-radius: 3px;
                    border: 1px solid #BDBDBD;
                }

            section#notices{
                display: inline-block;
                width: 75%;
            }
                section#notices .alert, section#notices .notice{
                    padding: 5px;
                    display: inline-block;
                }
                section#notices .alert{
                    background: #FA9191;
                    border: 1px solid #FC5D5D;
                }
                section#notices .notice{
                    background: #91A9FA;
                    border: 1px solid #5D82FC;
                }

            section#main h2{
                margin-top: 25px;
            }
            section#main p{
                margin-top: 5px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <h1>Site name</h1>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href='#'>Link 1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href='#'>Link 2</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href='#'>Link 3</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href='#'>Link 4</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href='#'>Link 5</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>

        <section id='quick_login'>
            <h2>Quick login</h2>
            <form action='login.php'>
                Username: <input type='text' placeholder='Your username' name='username' />
                <br />Password: <input type='password' placeholder='Your password' name='password' />
                <br /><input type='submit' value='Go' />
            </form>
        </section>

        <section id='notices'>
            <p class='alert'>
                Your email address hasn't been verified; check your email for a link to verify it.
            </p>
            <p class='notice'>
                We received a record 553 visitors yesterday!
            </p>
        </section>

        <section id='main'>
            <h2>Subtitle 1</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nisl risus, viverra eu sollicitudin volutpat, ultricies vel sapien. Cras in felis eu justo mattis convallis vel et orci. Maecenas consequat fermentum magna, sit amet dapibus nulla pulvinar venenatis. Nullam nulla mi, consectetur id diam at, pulvinar tempus diam. Morbi suscipit odio nec arcu ultricies dignissim. Curabitur consectetur libero lectus, ornare sodales tellus congue nec. Nam id tellus id nulla eleifend condimentum.</p>

            <h2>Subtitle 2</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris lacus nisi, mattis vitae volutpat tempus, suscipit nec lorem. Quisque posuere lectus odio, porttitor sagittis ligula ullamcorper quis. Vivamus ornare ut sapien in rutrum. Nullam et porttitor metus. Curabitur ornare orci sit amet aliquam rutrum. Phasellus scelerisque dignissim tellus in dictum. Pellentesque eu nibh purus. Nulla scelerisque sodales urna in feugiat. Maecenas et eleifend neque. Sed dolor turpis, congue et nisl quis, euismod bibendum magna. Sed eget laoreet urna.</p>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try the [W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org/). It will check your HTML or CSS (upload the style.css) for errors. If it doesn't work, I'm asking you to share your HTML-code or give a web address.

Comment: Well, thanks for making me check it. It turns out I had an invalid CSS property and I was using `<h1>Site name</h2>` (oops). However, even after fixing those, the problem is still persisting.

Comment: @whoami This is a comment and **not** an answer - although it is relevant and helpful I am surprised it hasn't been voted down as it  *doesn't answer the question*. In future please add comments like this as comments to the question (using the Add Comment box), reserving answers for solutions to the question posted. Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: I can't comment to the question because in must have 50 reputation. So I thought this is the only was to make contact.